# MVC3 .net Unobtrusive Javascript for RenderAction

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, unobtrusive-validation

I have a view that renders a 3 Partial views using 
@Html.Partial 
and another view using:
@Html.RenderAction as this partial view requires a different model to that of the other partials

I have the Server side validation working fine, but I can't get the client validation to work.
I have a field which is required, however, when I blank this out and move to the next field on the renderAction view, the validation is not firing (no red background - validation class not being set).
The field is set to Required in the underlying ViewModel.
I include the scripts in the renderAction View:

```
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")" type="text/javascript"></script> 
  <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")"                     
                                 type="text/javascript"></script> 
  <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" 
                 type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The tags for the fields are being set for unobtrusive javascript as expected:

```
<input id="user_Surname" class="names" type="text" value="gggg" title="Must be between 1 and 100 chars in length" name="user.Surname" data-val-required="Surname is required" data-val-length-max="50" data-val-length="Surname length must be between 0 and 50" data-val="true">
```

I've tried adding the following to the end of the RenderAction Partial View:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.parse();
</script>
```

But this doesn't help....
Not sure it makes any difference but the fields are all within an Ajax.BeginForm

Thanks in advance.....